# Invert scroll on rotate(180d)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll

Having a small problem. (Refer to fiddle)
I've got a container in my project that has been rotated 180 deg, with a container inside that has been rotated another 180 back to the original state.

I need to invert the scroll.
How would i go about this?

Dont mind wasting your time with a method, that reverts the basic setup.
The basic setup has to stay.

http://jsfiddle.net/vavxy36s/

Description of fiddle: 
"Start" marks the initial string and "end" ofcourse the last one.
If you try scrolling you will realize, that it's inverted as to how one would normally scroll.

```
.class1 {
    height: 200px;
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    width: 100px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    direction: rtl;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.class2 {
    direction: ltr;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

**EDIT: Just mousewheel scroll, has to be inverted.**

Comment: This seems like solving a problem that doesn't need to exist... Why do you need two 180deg-rotated elements inside each-other??

Comment: Did your client tell you the reason? There must be one, and I'm just curious to hear about it before even trying to do it.

Comment: Well, I honestly can't tell you much. Was hired to do front-end only, with a couple of requests, based on backend optimization. For some reason, the backend was optimized for a reserved container, seems wierd - I agree. Can't find any logic (not that I'm very competent with backend tho) in it.

Comment: Rasmus, your fiddle seems to work fine for me in Firefox 40. Mousewheel scrolling works as expected (although the scroll bar itself is on the left side). Maybe you should mention in the question which browsers (+versions) you've tried that are broken. Oh! I see your `transform`s are `-webkit`-prefixed, so I guess your issue is only with Chrome/Safari, or you are only targeting those browsers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Edit:** Your original setup has different behaviors in Chrome and in [IE & Firefox]. In Chrome, the scroll is already inverted, but in FF and IE, the scroll remains normal. My solution reverts it in both cases, but the behaviors remain different across browsers.

You could add these styles:

```
/* ...
   Your original styles
   ...
*/

.class1 {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.class2 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

And then, using jQuery, modify the `bottom` CSS property of `.class2`:

```
var scrollPos = 0,
    diff      = $('.class2').height() - $('.class1').height();


$('.class1').on('mousewheel', function(e) {
    scrollPos = Math.min(
                         0,
                         Math.max(
                                  -diff,
                                  scrollPos + e.originalEvent.wheelDelta
                        )
                );

    $('.class2').css('bottom', scrollPos);
});
```

### JS Fiddle Demo

Answer (score 1):

You could use the mousewheel library to catch and invert the scroll movement.

```
$(".class1").mousewheel(function(event) {

  event.preventDefault();

  this.scrollTop -= (event.deltaY * event.deltaFactor * -1);

});
```

You can view a demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/fduu20df/1/